# How to set attribute of a webElement in Protractor?

Tags: node.js, class, dom, attributes, protractor

I'm using Protractor 2 and want to change the class attribute of a `webElement`.

Pretend I have this `menuWrapper` element which I need to append `show` to its class attribute.

What is the easiest way to achieve this? Except for `browser.executeScript()`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without the use of `browser.executeScript` - though I'm curious to see if anyone has an answer.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find any other ways too, thought someone might know a trick or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Selenium WebDriver specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html) (which `WebDriverJS` and hence `Protractor` follow/use) does not have anything documented for setting an element's attribute, only for [getting an element's attribute](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#get-element-attribute). In other words, you won't find anything built-in for this task.

Certainly, the easiest way to set an element's attribute would be to use `executeScript()`.

Comment: That's what I thought too, just had to be sure I'm not missing anything. Thanks @alecxe